# ¿Estaría bien cambiar estado-pordiseño por estado-por-diseño?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, etiquetas

Veo esta respuesta de @toledano:

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1559/13558

> [estado-pordiseño](/questions/tagged/estado-pordise%c3%b1o)
>
> En la revisión de publicaciones, cuando es una respuesta, el cuadro de opciones de eliminación presenta un texto confuso:
>
> ...

Veo esa etiqueta, que la verdad creo que queda mal poner **estado-pordiseño**, y pienso que sería mejor **estado-por-diseño**, o **estado-diseño**.

¿Qué piensan? ¿Lo dejamos como está ahora?

Comment: ¡Bien visto! Supongo que fue un gazapo y yo lo etiquetaría como "característica-nueva" para que se haga.

Comment: @fedorqui Listo, editado.

Comment: Supongo que se hizo así copiando a las etiquetas en inglés (ej: [meta-tag:status-bydesign] o [meta-tag:status-norepro])... -No digo que tenga que ser así (me da igual, pero me parece muy bien que traigas el tema), sólo comento por qué creo que se hizo de esa forma.

Comment: De hecho también hay _estado-enrevisión_ y _estado-norepro_ ([lista](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=newest))

Comment: Yo creo que es correcto dejarlo como `estado-pordiseño`. Es como `categoría-subcategoría`... solo que unen todas las palabras de subcategoría para homogeneizar un solo guión.

Comment: Se creó el sinónimo. Ver: [Hice un sinónimo de la etiqueta featured y ahora se llama destacado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1980/127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pordiseño no es una palabra que aparece en el diccionario de la RAE.

Por lo que animo a que corregir ese error ortográfico y cualquier otro similar. La calidad del sitio también se demuestra en esto.

Comment: Listo... Ahora están creados los sinónimos: [meta-tag:estado-por-diseño], [meta-tag:estado-no-reproducido] y [meta-tag:estado-en-revisión] pero lo único que no sé, es que los 2 últimos, se pongan en color.

Comment: Acá en Argentina, ENRE significa **Ente Nacional Regulador de la Electricidad**, por lo que se podría confundir con ENRE Visión... Creo que cuanto menos confuso sea, mejor.