# Hice un sinónimo de la etiqueta featured y ahora se llama destacado

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Con la [respuesta de @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1979), hice un sinónimo sobre las etiqueta [estado-pordiseño](/questions/tagged/estado-pordise%c3%b1o), con [estado-por-diseño](/questions/tagged/estado-por-dise%c3%b1o) y otras.

> [estado-pordiseño](/questions/tagged/estado-pordise%c3%b1o) a [estado-por-diseño](/questions/tagged/estado-por-dise%c3%b1o)
>   [estado-norepro](/questions/tagged/estado-norepro) a [estado-no-reproducido](/questions/tagged/estado-no-reproducido)
>   [estado-enrevision](/questions/tagged/estado-enrevision) a [estado-en-revisión](/questions/tagged/estado-en-revisi%c3%b3n)

No estoy seguro si es un problema de la cache de mi navegador o si algún administrador del sitio, ya sea @JuanM o @Konamiman tengan que ponerle el color tirando a rojo claro a las etiquetas.

La cuestión es que ahora hice un sinónimo, y ahora cambio esto:

> [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) a [destacado](/questions/tagged/destacado)

Quedando como etiqueta maestra, la segunda. Esa también, por algún motivo, el color no me aparece en la segunda. Estuve mirando, y ahora veo que el color rojo significa que los únicos que pueden publicar en estas etiquetas, son los moderadores, y creo que cambiar eso es un tema de administradores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya está solucionado. Se muestran los colores en las etiquetas maestras.

Al parecer solo era cuestión de tiempo.

Comment: ¿O sea que no es una lista hardcodeada? Es bueno saberlo.